# connect on "connection less" boost::asio::ip::udp::socket

Tags: networking, udp, boost-asio

I've been learning about UDP socket lately by browsing the net and all the pages that were explaining it were mentioning that UDP sockets are "connection less". This, if I understand it correctly means that one does not have a "connection" between two sockets but instead shoots datagram packets to specified endpoints without knowing whether the other end is listening.

Then I go and start reading the boost::asio::ip::udp::socket [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__udp/socket.html) and find that it mentions API like:

- async_connect: Start an asynchronous **connect**.
- async_receive: Start an asynchronous receive on a **connected socket**.
- async_send: Start an asynchronous send on a **connected socket**.

Now this is a bit confusing for a novice. I can find 3 possible causes for my confusion (in order of likehood :) )

1. I'm missing something
2. The asio implementation is doing something behind the scenes to virtualize the connection.
3. The documentation is wrong

There is also a slight glitch in the docs, when you open the page for [basic_datagram_socket::async_connect](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_datagram_socket/async_connect.html) the example in there is instantiating **TCP** sockets (instead of **UDP** ones).

Would someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Single UNIX specification has a better explanation of what [connect](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xns/connect.html) does for connection-less sockets:

> If the initiating socket is not connection-mode, then connect() sets the socket's peer address, but no connection is made. For SOCK_DGRAM sockets, the peer address identifies where all datagrams are sent on subsequent send() calls, and limits the remote sender for subsequent recv() calls.

Comment: +1 and if it wasn't obvious, this is confusion #1 in the original question.